# xgb.cv with no folds and return the results based on a split of the data

Tags: r, xgboost

I have some data which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 50 x 28
   sanchinarro date       holiday weekday weekend workday_on_holi… weekend_on_holi… protocol_active
         <dbl> <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>
 1      -1.01  2010-01-01       1       1       0                1                0               0
 2       0.832 2010-01-02       0       0       1                0                0               0
 3       1.29  2010-01-03       0       0       1                0                0               0
 4       1.04  2010-01-04       0       1       0                0                0               0
 5       0.526 2010-01-05       0       1       0                0                0               0
 6      -0.292 2010-01-06       1       1       0                1                0               0
 7      -0.394 2010-01-07       0       1       0                0                0               0
 8      -0.547 2010-01-08       0       1       0                0                0               0
 9      -0.139 2010-01-09       0       0       1                0                0               0
10       0.628 2010-01-10       0       0       1                0                0               0
```

I want to run `xgb.cv` on the first 40 rows and validate it on the final 10 rows.

I try the following:

```
library(xgboost)
library(dplyr)
X_Val <- ddd %>% select(-c(1:2))
Y_Val <- ddd %>% select(c(1)) %>% pull()

dVal <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(X_Val), label = as.numeric(Y_Val))
xgb.cv(data = dVal, nround = 30, folds = NA, params = list(eta = 0.1, max_depth = 5))
```

which gives me this error:

> Error in xgb.cv(data = dVal, nround = 30, folds = NA, eta = 0.1,
>   max_depth = 5) :    'folds' must be a list with 2 or more elements
>   that are vectors of indices for each CV-fold

How can I run a simple `xgb.cv` on the first 40 rows and test it on the last 10 rows.

I eventually want to apply a gird search with a list of parameters and save the results in a list. Since I am dealing with time series data I do not want to mix the folds up, I just want a simple train and in-sample test of 40:10.

Data:

```
        ddd <- structure(list(sanchinarro = c(-1.00742964973274, 0.832453587904369, 
1.29242439731365, 1.03688505875294, 0.525806381631517, -0.291919501762755, 
-0.394135237187039, -0.547458840323464, -0.138595898626329, 0.628022117055801, 
1.19020866188936, 1.5990716035865, 1.5990716035865, -0.70078244345989, 
2.11015028070792, 1.95682667757149, 0.985777191040795, 0.883561455616511, 
0.985777191040795, 0.270267043070807, 2.51901322240505, 2.41679748698077, 
0.372482778495091, -0.291919501762755, -0.905213914308458, -0.905213914308458, 
-0.649674575747748, 1.2413165296015, 1.54796373587436, -0.70078244345989, 
-0.905213914308458, -0.0363801632020448, 1.54796373587436, 2.00793454528363, 
1.54796373587436, -0.445243104899181, -0.445243104899181, 1.03688505875294, 
0.628022117055801, -0.496350972611323, 0.168051307646523, -0.649674575747748, 
0.0658355722222391, -1.00742964973274, -0.291919501762755, 0.0147277045100972, 
0.168051307646523, -0.189703766338471, 0.219159175358665, 0.679129984767943
), date = structure(c(14610, 14611, 14612, 14613, 14614, 14615, 
14616, 14617, 14618, 14619, 14620, 14621, 14622, 14623, 14624, 
14625, 14626, 14627, 14628, 14629, 14630, 14631, 14632, 14633, 
14634, 14635, 14636, 14637, 14638, 14639, 14640, 14641, 14642, 
14643, 14644, 14645, 14646, 14647, 14648, 14649, 14650, 14651, 
14652, 14653, 14654, 14655, 14656, 14657, 14658, 14659), class = "Date"), 
    holiday = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weekday = c(1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), weekend = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), workday_on_holiday = c(1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weekend_on_holiday = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), protocol_active = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), text_broken_clouds = c(0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), text_clear = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), text_fog = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), text_partly_cloudy = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), text_partly_sunny = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), text_passing_clouds = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), text_scattered_clouds = c(1, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), text_sunny = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), month_1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1), month_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_4 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), month_8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_9 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

EDIT: List data:

The final data comes in the form of lists.

```
datalst <- list(structure(list(sanchinarro = c(-1.00742964973274, 0.832453587904369, 
1.29242439731365, 1.03688505875294, 0.525806381631517, -0.291919501762755, 
-0.394135237187039, -0.547458840323464, -0.138595898626329, 0.628022117055801, 
1.19020866188936, 1.5990716035865, 1.5990716035865, -0.70078244345989
), date = structure(c(14610, 14611, 14612, 14613, 14614, 14615, 
14616, 14617, 14618, 14619, 14620, 14621, 14622, 14623), class = "Date"), 
    holiday = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weekday = c(1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), weekend = c(0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), workday_on_holiday = c(1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weekend_on_holiday = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), protocol_active = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), text_broken_clouds = c(0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), text_clear = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), text_fog = c(0, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), text_partly_cloudy = c(0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), text_partly_sunny = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), text_passing_clouds = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), text_scattered_clouds = c(1, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), text_sunny = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_1 = c(1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), month_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_9 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), month_10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), month_11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), month_12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L)), structure(list(sanchinarro = c(0.832179838392013, 1.29225734336885, 
1.03665872949283, 0.525461501740789, -0.292454062662475, -0.394693508212883, 
-0.548052676538495, -0.139094894336863, 0.627700947291197, 1.19001789781844, 
1.59897568002007, 1.59897568002007, -0.701411844864107, 2.11017290777211
), date = structure(c(14611, 14612, 14613, 14614, 14615, 14616, 
14617, 14618, 14619, 14620, 14621, 14622, 14623, 14624), class = "Date"), 
    holiday = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weekday = c(0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), weekend = c(1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), workday_on_holiday = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weekend_on_holiday = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), protocol_active = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), text_broken_clouds = c(1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), text_clear = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), text_fog = c(1, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), text_partly_cloudy = c(1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), text_partly_sunny = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), text_passing_clouds = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), text_scattered_clouds = c(1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), text_sunny = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), month_1 = c(1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), month_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_9 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), month_10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), month_11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), month_12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L)), structure(list(sanchinarro = c(1.29293502084952, 1.03729933727253, 
0.526027970118536, -0.292006217327851, -0.394260490758649, -0.547641900904846, 
-0.138624807181653, 0.628282243549334, 1.19068074741873, 1.59969784114192, 
1.59969784114192, -0.701023311051044, 2.11096920829591, 1.95758779814971
), date = structure(c(14612, 14613, 14614, 14615, 14616, 14617, 
14618, 14619, 14620, 14621, 14622, 14623, 14624, 14625), class = "Date"), 
    holiday = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weekday = c(0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), weekend = c(1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), workday_on_holiday = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weekend_on_holiday = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), protocol_active = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), text_broken_clouds = c(0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), text_clear = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), text_fog = c(0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), text_partly_cloudy = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), text_partly_sunny = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), text_passing_clouds = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), text_scattered_clouds = c(0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), text_sunny = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), month_1 = c(1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), month_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_9 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), month_10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), month_11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), month_12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L)))
```

EDIT:

I **think** this gives me what I am after - I need to double/tripple check it. (if you see any errors please let me know)

```
splt <- 0.80 * nrow(ddd)
ddd[c(1:splt), "id"] = 1
ddd$id[is.na(ddd$id)] = 2


fold.ids <- unique(ddd$id)

custom.folds <- vector("list", length(fold.ids))
i <- 1
for( id in fold.ids){
  custom.folds[[i]] <- which( ddd$id %in% id )
  i <- i+1
}

custom.folds

cv <- xgb.cv(params = list(eta = 0.1, max_depth = 5), dVal, nround = 10, folds = custom.folds, prediction = TRUE)
cv$evaluation_log
```

I now need to find a way to apply this to all 3 lists in the "new" added data.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should split the data onto `dtrain` (40 first rows) and `dval` (10 last rows). Secondly, you need rather `xgb.train`, not `xgb.cv`.

So, your code should be modified to something like that:

```
library(xgboost)
library(dplyr)
# you code regarding ddd
X <- ddd %>% select(-c(1:2))
Y <- ddd %>% select(c(1)) %>% pull()
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(X[1:40,]), label = as.numeric(Y[1:40,]))
dval   <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(X[41:50,]), label = as.numeric(Y[41:50,]))
watchlist <- list(train=dtrain, val=dval)
model <- xgb.train(data=dtrain, watchlist=watchlist, nround = 30, eta = 0.1, max_depth = 5)
```

IMHO, 40+10 rows only and so sparse features give no hope to obtain good results using XGBoost.

Comment: Thanks! I have more data than the 40 + 10 shown here. How could I use `xgb.train` using a grid search. My goal is to find the best parameters but I don't see how `xgb.train` can be used to do this? I added a small edit to the original post also.

Comment: Using grid search based on `xgb.cv` makes no sense in the case of timeseries - the results will be overfitted because most of the folds working as valid will be created inside, not at the edge of the dataset. Try to make the optimization manually, and if the results are optimistic, use Bayesian Optimization, package `rBayesianOptimization`.

Comment: Thanks, I will actually use Bayesian Optimisation once I can get the code working. I have 1000 different time series datasets. Each dataset contains 365 * 5 years. Each dataset shifts along by 1 day. Say the data starts Jan 1st 2000 then the first dataset will end on December 31 2005. The second dataset starts Jan 2nd 2000 and ends Jan 1st 2006, the third starts Jan 3rd 2000 and ends Jan 2nd 2006 etc. Its impossible for me to run CV on all datasets so I randomly sample them to apply CV and eventually I want to average out the results from each of the cross validation models randomly generated

Comment: I am hoping this would then give me the "best" parameters over a sample of the data. Which will act as my KFold cross validation, whilst preserving the time series structure. Not sure if this makes sense, however.

Comment: Regarding your actual version of custom folds to use xgb.cv, it will not work as you would wish. It will create two runs, the first one with 80% train and 20% valid, and the second one with 20% train and 80% valid (sic!).

Comment: Ah yes I see! hmm I wonder if there is a way to just save the first one and discard the second one.